# What is the error in the given code on 9th line?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, typedef, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have created an alias of the struct pointer as NODE.Using this I am allocating a memory space,but it is showing error.What is the error?

```
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

typedef struct node *NODE;

NODE getnode()
{
    NODE p=(NODE)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    return p;
}
```

It's showing compilation error.

Comment: Print out `sizeof(NODE))`. The result may surprise you.

Comment: It's showing 4.

Comment: and what size do you expect for a structure containing 1 integer and 2 pointers?

Comment: [Seems to compile fine](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/d9iM70).

Comment: Ah screw being oblique. I need to go to sleep. `NODE` is a pointer to a `node`. So `sizeof(NODE)` is the size of a pointer to a `node`. You want the size of a `node`, `sizeof(node)`.

Comment: It's a bad idea to typedef pointers, as it's really important to know where the pointers are in your code. It's an even worse idea to typedef a pointer with a name that hides the fact that it is a pointer.

Comment: You tagged the question as `c++`, so you probably want to code `C++` and not `C`. So you really shouldn't use malloc.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in your comment, you allocate not enough amount of memory for your structure.

Your structure takes 4 bytes x 3 (4 for integer and 4 for each pointer).

You allocate only 4 bytes. The reason is that you pass to `sizeof` function **pointer to structure** instead of **structure**. So you allocate memory for **pointer to structure** instead of **structure**.

You need to change `sizeof(NODE)` into `sizeof(node)`.

P.S. Size of some types like `int` and pointers depends on computer architecture. Typically on 32-bit machines they are smaller then on 64-bit.

Comment: Probably right, but the actual problem wasn't stated in the question so we don't really know what was being asked.

Comment: I see the problem so I answered to it :) But you have right that problem wasn't stated properly. However you should be easygoing as far as this may be first question of this user :)

Comment: What's done's done. Do me a favour and recommend they use `new`. It'll get the size right.

Comment: I got my answer.thanks @BartekPL

Comment: @user4581301 Of course, if somebody has problem with malloc, shouldn't use it as far as there are better possibilities like (new/delete or smart pointers).

Comment: @Yatharth You then should upvote and accept the answer.